# Openssl - AES-256-ECB decrypt with key, bad magic number

Tags: encryption, openssl

Im trying to decrypt a text, which was encrypted with AES-256-ECB with the given key. To decrypt, Im using the same version of the openssl which was used for encryption (OpenSSL 1.1.1d 10 Sep 2019).

String to decrypt: `VAWawVAWawxiyH20dI+t5NPAY9w==` (inside file.txt)
Key: `461a966faef244e4808d6b2b8e928d01` (inside key.txt)

I tried those commands:

```
cat file.txt | base64 -d > file2.txt 

openssl enc -AES-256-ECB -d -in file2.txt -out answer.txt --kfile key.txt
```

And im getting: `bad magic number`. Whats the problem?

Answer (score 2):

`openssl enc` will normally use a password to derive a key. So it is the derived key that is used to decrypt the file. The derivation process requires a "salt", and `openssl enc` during encryption stores that salt at the beginning of the file along with a "magic number" to identify it. If the magic number is missing (usually because the file wasn't encrypted by `openssl enc` or because the password based key derivation derivation method wasn't used) then you get this error.

The `-kfile` option tells OpenSSL to read the password from a file and then derive the key from it. Probably want you intended was to not use password derivation at all, but to use the explicit key. In which case you need to use the `-K` option and supply the key on the command line using hex.

Comment: To be precise, the number is not really a number, it is the ASCII string `Salted__` added in front of the 8 byte salt and ciphertext. You can easily see it in a hex editor - if it is present of course.